# Почему высота div больше высоты контента

Tags: css

По какой-то причине длина div с классом thumb получается длиннее суммы длины содержимого этого div на 2-3px. Если поставить background-color, то под изображением появится небольшая полоска. Как этого избежать?

```
<div class ="wrapper">
    <div class = "thumb">
        <div>Текст</div>
        <div><img src="Картинка.jpg"></div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Стили

```
.wrapper{
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;

}

.thumb{
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 35px;


}

.thumb img{
   width: 100%;
   height:auto;
   margin-top: 10px;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

или родителю img - line:height: 0;

Пример

```css
.thumb {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.thumb img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.block-parent-img-line-height {
  line-height: 0;
}

.thumb .block-parent-img{
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumb">
  <div>C line-height 0</div>
  <div class="block-parent-img block-parent-img-line-height"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
</div>

<div class="thumb">
  <div>Без line-height 0</div>
  <div class="block-parent-img"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: в текущем примере - разницы как-то не заметно. Можешь как-нибудь выделить, чтобы было видно, что примеры отличаются? А, увидел рамку при наведении. Может стоит ее постоянной сделать?

Comment: @Grundy - поправил

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию изображение имеет значение `display:inline-block;` и имеет выравнивание `vertical-align:baseline;` что и добавляет вертикальный отступ снизу. Исходя из этого есть 2 варианта:

1 - Добавьте изображению свойство `display:block;`

2 - Добавьте изображению свойство `vertical-align:top;` или `vertical-align:bottom;`

Comment: разве при _vertical-align:top;_ отступ снизу уберется?

Comment: @Grundy емнип, у меня убирался всегда у любого vertical-align отличного от baseline

Comment: да, в том то и дело, что baseline выравнивает по базовой линии родителя, если родительский элемент не имеет базовой линии, то появляется отсуп